# VMWARE ERROR : Transport (VMDB) error -14: Pipe connection has been broken

Tags: updates, vmware-workstation

I updated my windows 10 and I can't run my Virtual machine, I got this error :

**Transport (VMDB) error -14: Pipe connection has been broken.**

I tried what is proposed by VMWare without result :/
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361

Any help will be appreciated

Regards

Comment: same issue here... nothing work so far and no clue about the root cause...

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I fixed it!

What work for me was to disable the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Search for "**Turn Windows Features on or off**", next, a window will pop up.

Scroll down until you find:

- Windows Subsystem for Linux - Uncheck

Also make sure that:

- Hyper-V
- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hipervisor Platform

: Are unckecked/Disabled

It takes some time to configure, after that reboot the system, and it should run again!

---

Update

This is a more reliable solution:

Download  "Device Guard and Credential Guard hardware readiness tool" from Microsoft:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337

- Execute .\DG_Readiness.ps1 -Capable in PowerShell to install the driver if needed
- Reboot
- Execute  .\DG_Readiness.ps1 -Disable
- Reboot
- On boot follow the instructions do disable DG/CG

DONE!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. First solution worked for me combined with a restart. Or maybe the restart would have been enough.

Comment: Contrary to your advice, the "Windows Hypervisor Platform" is what makes the modern Virtualization-Based Security feature of Windows play nice with third-party hypervisors like VMware. But I suppose the version of either have to be at a given minimum version. So YMMV.

Comment: Additionally "Windows Sandbox" should also be unchecked as it relies on Hyper-V.